# The controller with the name 'greetingController' is not registered

Tags: angularjs, laravel, controller

I am having problem with my AngularJS and Laravel.

Here is the error

> The controller with the name 'greetingController' is not registered

app.js

```
require('angular');

var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

 myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<head>
    <script src="{{ asset("js/manifest.js") }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset("js/vendor.js") }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset("js/app.js") }}"></script>
</head>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="greetingController">
      @{{greeting}}                                 
</div>
```

webpack

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
| for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
| file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
|
*/

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract(['angular']);
```

Comment: You define your controller as GreetingController but put greetingController in ng-controller directive - notice different case of the first character.

Comment: still the same error does it have to do on the way I did on the webpack ?

Comment: i use the chrome devtools and found this while debugging 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions

Answer (score 0):

The names of the controllers are case sensitive. Therefore `greetingController` and `GreetingController` are not the same.

Simply refer to your controller as `GreetingController` in your code.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
      @{{greeting}}                                 
</div>
```

Comment: still the same error does it have to do on the way I did on the webpack ?

Comment: i use the chrome devtools and found this while debugging 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions